# How can I map through an object in react js?

Tags: reactjs, object, axios

Here is the response from the server

[image: 1]

How to fetch the "msg" in ResponseText from response.

```
{"errors":[{"value":"","msg":"Invalid value","param":"name","location":"body"},{"value":"","msg":"Invalid value","param":"description","location":"body"},{"value":"","msg":"Invalid value","param":"catid","location":"body"}]}
```

Comment: try this: `response.errors.map(error => error.msg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution.

```js
const Example = () => {
  const errors = {
    "errors": [{
      "value": "",
      "msg": "Invalid value",
      "param": "name",
      "location": "body"
    }, {
      "value": "",
      "msg": "Invalid value",
      "param": "description",
      "location": "body"
    }, {
      "value": "",
      "msg": "Invalid value",
      "param": "catid",
      "location": "body"
    }]
  }



  return ( < div >
  
 {errors["errors"].map((item, id) => (

<h1 key={id} >  {item.msg} </h1>
 ))}




    <
    /div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( <
  Example title = "Example using Hooks:" / >
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```